# QGIS print composer internal grid labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, grids-graticules

Is there a way to have the grid labelled inside of the map frame (I don't mean the option to draw coordinates inside the frame)? What I want to achieve is a "ladder" of labels like in this example:

http://www.freytagberndt.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/9007868048732_Blattschnitt03.jpg

Not only near the borders of the frame but also repeatedly inside (because the maps are usually quite large). That's why the "Inside frame" option is not sufficient.

Comment: Grid labels that repeat across the map at set horizontal and vertical intervals. If there is a way of doing this I think it will be via the 'Custom' option under 'Draw coordinates.' I don't know enough about scripting to be of help I'm afraid, but it would be very useful facility to have.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, You need this
[image: inside label]

Comment: Yes, that's more or less what I need. But not only near the borders of the frame but also repeatedly inside (because the maps are usually quite large). That's why  the "Inside frame" option is not sufficient.